# Fetwa about pieces of the relegion

Tags: halal-haram

Hello what is the judgment for people who accept religion of God partially? For example : Declare that there is only one God and Muhammad is his Messenger and than say : No need to pray, or fasting is stupid and things like that .

Comment: We are not a fatwa site. Maybe my answer on [Conditions to do fatiha for marriage](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/48262/conditions-to-do-fatiha-for-mariage/48290#48290) is relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone believes Allah, the he should believe the source of his belief too(It must be Qura'n and Hadith. Nothing else describes Allah directly). Then if he believes in Qura'n, in it's verse 42 and 43 Allah has said,

> "What put you into Saqar(Jahannam/Hell)?" They will say, "We were not of those who prayed,"

So I think the person who says there's no need to pray, it may be right if he wanna enter the Jahannam or Hell(as he wants he has no need to pray). Or if he wanna go to Jannat, not to pray Salah is nothing but stupidity.

Then go to the subject of fasting,
From Quran:

> "The month of Ramadan (is the month) in which the Qur’an has been sent down as guidance for mankind containing clear signs which lead (to the straight road) and distinguishing (the truth from falsehood).." (Q 2:185)

Also if a man can't be able to fast he has to feed the same quality and amount of food to someone else. Or if he breaks his fast willingly then he has to take 3 days of fasting for each days he had broken the fast.

Suppose he also believes in Muhammad and only 3 prophets(Who asked the Question wanted to know in the comment box). But he is not right. Because there are existence of name of 25 prophets(some of them are Rasul too). Muhammad(Peace of Allah and Rahmat Allah be upon him) has said,

> "There were 1,24,000(2,24,000 in some books) prophets including me"

In Quran:

> We certainly sent into every nation a messenger (16:36)

And believing Allah and his Messenger without believing it is foolish work. Isn't it? So this type of Fetwa(**eg.** No need to pray) should not be given.

Comment: Good answer although I was actually not talking only for fasting or salah . Lets say a person who accepts only 3 prophets of islam instead of all of them ... Is this an ignorant , kafir , or stupid?

Comment: I edited the answer for your additional question. See it again. And you shouldn't also say anyone kafir who believes in Allah. It may be dangerous for you. He may be stupid. Make him understood